# Unable to set up dual monitor in CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, xorg, dual-monitor

I need use **two** different `X11` `DISPLAY`s for **two** different UI application on **two** different phisical monitors.
Each application on each monitor.

Configuration:

- `VDI` output: `Acer K192HQL`
- `HDMI via VDI` output: PHL 193V5
- `OS`: `CentOS release 6.9 (Final)`

Here is `Xorg` configuration:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen         "Screen0" LeftOf "Screen1"
        Screen         "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
        Option "DontZap" "yes"
        Option "BlankTime" "0"
        Option "StandbyTime" "0"
        Option "SuspendTime" "0"
        Option "OffTime" "0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        ModelName    "LCD Panel 1280x1024"
        HorizSync    31.5 - 67.0
        VertRefresh  50.0 - 75.0
        Option      "dpms"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Videocard0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
                Modes    "1280x1024"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor1"
        #ModelName    "LCD Panel 1280x1024"
        #HorizSync    31.5 - 67.0
        #VertRefresh  50.0 - 75.0
        Option      "dpms"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen1"
        Device     "Videocard0"
        Monitor    "Monitor1"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
                Modes    "1280x1024"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x1024     60.02 +
   1920x1080     59.50 +
   1400x1050     59.98
   1280x960      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   640x480       59.94
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79 +
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00
   1024x768      75.08*   70.07    60.00
   832x624       74.55
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00
   720x400       70.08
HDMI1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1280x1024     75.02 +  60.02
   1366x768      59.79 +
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94
   1280x720      60.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.08*   60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So, as you see I have just `Screen 0`, but I need two screens for send each application to it's dedicated screen (`DISPLAY`).

Also I have this message in system settings:

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/olgapshen/logs/blob/main/xorg.0.log) is the `Xorg.0.log`.